# Can't Inject Web 3 in my Dapp using MetaMask

Tags: javascript, ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js, metamask

I have a simple HTML file with below code trying to connect to my Smart contract from Chrome.

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
            console.log(web3);
        } else {
            // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
            web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
        }
```

With my localhost:8545 code works perfectly, but when I stop localhost, its just not connecting through MetaMask plugin. I tried everything, closing browser, logging out of MetaMask and logging back in fresh page, reinstalling MetaMask. Nothing works. My refresh page keeps on looking for localhost connection.

Comment: To which network are you connected with metamask? You may be connected to your localhost with metamask.

Comment: Marcos, I am connected to Roopsten while trying my sample DApp. web3.currentProvider still shows LocalHost. Can I force web3.currentProvider to set to RoopSten or to any other network of my choice?

Comment: Are you including a `web3.js` yourself, `<script src="/somepath/web3.js"></script>` ?

Comment: I am not including any web3.js file exclusively. I am relying on metamask to inject. Do I need to? Is it possible that I need to run my test HTML file in web server to enable metamask inject web3? Right now I am trying above code by simply launching HTML file from my C: drive into chrome.

Comment: No, you don't need to, but if you were, that would have cause your error. What URL are you trying to access?, does `console.log(web3)` get printed?

Comment: Marcos,It worked for me actually. I need to launch my site in localhost. I build .aspx page and launched in localhost. I can see now that web3 is not undefined. Always fun to work in Visual studio